# Azure Data Factory - copy data activity into a Postgresql database (on an IaaS Windows Azure vm, not Azure Database for Postgresql (PaaS))

Tags: postgresql, azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I have a Postgresql database on a Windows vm (not a PaaS Azure Database), and I need to import csv files into it daily.  ADF seems like a perfect fit, but I see that a standard Postgresql db is not a dataset option for the Sink in the Copy Data activity.  Is there any way to get this done in ADF?  If not, could I please get some recommendations on other tools that include scheduling and alerting?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Kindly create the linked service of "Azure Database for PostgreSQL" and Enter your Onpremises PostgreSQL Database details Manually. Use the Self Hosted Integration Run time when you are connecting to On premises Resources.